# How to see a function is Gaussian

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, gaussian-integral

I have this function $$f(x, y) = \frac {1}{2\pi}\exp(−0.5(x^2-2xy+9y^2))$$

I proceed like this:

First I compute $\Sigma^{-1}$
which is   \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1&  9\end{bmatrix} 
Then I see the determinant is positive (which is good) but I don't know how to proceed.

My principal question is this: The value of the det $\Sigma^{-1}$ has to be between precise values or it just has to be $>0$ in order to be a Gaussian density??

Comment: it can be whatever you want. Once you prove that the PDF $f(x,y)$ is proportional to $\exp(z^T \Sigma^{-1} z)$ with $z = (x,y)$ for some matrix $\Sigma$ then good to go

Comment: Can you please let me see how would you solve it? Because with this density I'm not able to prove it is Gaussian... It looks like to me it is not...

Comment: you can write $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-0.5((x,y)\Sigma^{-1}(x,y))$ here because $(x,y)\Sigma^{-1}(x,y) = x^2 - 2xy +9y^2$. Hence it is gaussian with mean 0 and variance matrix $\Sigma$. It should include the factor of $\frac{1}{2\pi}\det\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ at the front. 

If you integrate the density over $\mathbb{R}^2$ you get $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, which is $(\det\Sigma)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \det(\Sigma^{-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, so this tells us we are correct.

Comment: The condition on the variance matrix is that it be positive-definite. For 2-by-2 matrices (so two variables) this requires the diagonal elements to be positive along with the determinant. If one wants more variables, the conditions get progressively stronger.

Answer (score 1):

> My principal question is this: The value of the $\det \Sigma^{-1}$ has to be between precise values or it just has to be >0 in order to be a Gaussian density??

A non-zero determinant is a necessary but not sufficient condition. The main thing you need to check for is that $\Sigma^{-1}$ is positive definite so that it is invertible. Also to be complete, we need a scaling factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^k \det \Sigma}}$, multiplying the exponential to have a Gaussian PDF.